# HKEY_USERS access Wow6432Node

Tags: c++, registry, poco

This is my program where I would like to list:

> HKEY_USERS/User_SID/**Wow6432Node**/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall/

```
#include "pch.h"

void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        HKEY root = HKEY_USERS;
        std::string sid("S-1-5-21-1917061056-2319448781-3348045073-1000");
        std::string subKey(sid + "\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\");
        Poco::Util::WinRegistryKey key(root, subKey, true, KEY_WOW64_32KEY);

        Poco::Util::WinRegistryKey::Keys keys;
        if (key.exists())
        {
            key.subKeys(keys);
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        _tcout << _T("Error occurred: ") << e.what() << std::endl;

        _tostringstream error;
        error << L"Error: " << e.what();
        ::MessageBox(NULL, error.str().c_str(), L"Error occurred", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

As far as I know in order to [switch between 64 and 32 registry keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx) we need to use KEY_WOW64_32KEY and KEY_WOW64_64KEY access mask. So I am using KEY_WOW64_32KEY but my program always lists:

> HKEY_USERS/User_SID/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall/

What am I doing wrong?

P.S: If we change HKEY_USERS on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE the program will work correctly.

Comment: That would be a bug, the Wow6432Node subkey normally only appears In the HKLM hive. Messing with uninstallers for users other than the one that's logged in is also a rather bad idea.  Well, it is a bad idea period.

Comment: Plus, if the other user hasn't logged in recently, it's entirely possible that their registry hive isn't loaded anyway...

Comment: So, how can i do listing of HKEY_USERS/User_SID/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall/ registry key? Is it correct to use hardcode path: HKEY_USERS/Wow6432Node/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall/

Comment: Does anybody know?